# "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found" force download of .step file in IIS7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have a website in witch i need to enable download of .step files. I try to add an handler in IIS but I stil get an error.

My handler is :

- Path : *.step
- Path Type : File or Folder
- Handler : StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule

So it's the same as StaticFile, anyone can tell me why staticFile handler is not taking care of these files?

The error I get is :

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page
>   you are requesting cannot be served
>   because of the extension
>   configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file
>   should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

This is in a MVC.Net application

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create a MIME map? see: http://sebastienlachance.com/post/Adding-a-MIME-map-in-IIS.aspx

Comment: Gosh! I added the handler but forgot about the mime-type... Thank You!